# Pegar Coordenadas de Geolocalização (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma simples aplicação que pega as coordenadas geográficas do google maps api. Está funcionando, porém não estou conseguindo pegar os valores que estão na outra função. Na verdade apenas quero uma maneira de pegar os valores de Latitude e Longitude para dentro do objeto mapCoordinates.

```
var App = React.createClass({



getInitialState(){


    GMaps.geolocate({
    success: function(position) {

        //alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        //"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); //dessa
//forma funciona porém quero pegar os valores de Latitude e Longitude //no return


        var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        var userLng = position.coords.longitude;    

    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('Geolocation failed: '+error.message);
    },
    not_supported: function() {
        alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
    },
    always: function() {
        //alert("Done!");
    },

    });

    return {

        mapCoordinates: {

            //lat: userLat, //aqui que devo obter o valor de userLat 
            //lng: userLng //aqui que devo obert o valor de userLng

        }                           

    }


},

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa função `success` é assíncrona. Usa o `this.setState` usando `.bind` ou passando o `this` por referência assim:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {

      // Extract the favorite locations from local storage

      var favorites = [];
      var self = this;

      if (localStorage.favorites) {
        favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.favorites);
      }

      GMaps.geolocate({
        success: function(position) {
          var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
          var userLng = position.coords.longitude;
          self.setState({
            mapCoordinates: {
              lat: userLat,
              lng: userLng
            }
          });
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!!