# Porque meu .map não é executado?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function (markers) {
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
  const geocodingResults = []
  markers.forEach((latLong) => {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latLong }, (result, status) => {
      // console.log(results, status)
      if (status !== 'OK') { return false }
      geocodingResults.push(result)
    })
  })
  console.log('geocodingResults', geocodingResults)
  return geocodingResults.map((address) => {
    console.log('address', address)
    return address[0].address_components[1].short_name
  })
}
```

No console eu recebo geocodingResults sendo um array com 2 de tamanho porem nunca recebo o log "address", oque pode esta acontecendo ? meu map não esta sendo executado ?

Comment: Qual resultado de `console.log('geocodingResults', geocodingResults)` ?

Comment: esse: https://pastebin.com/eXtvspBq

Comment: Já testou retirar o return antes do **map**? Ao invés de return coloque uma variável, e fora do map de um console na variável.

Comment: Pode adicionar o resultado de `console.log(JSON.stringify(geocodingResults))` para ficar mais fácil de visualizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse método `geocoder.geocode` é assíncrono. Isso quer dizer que a linha `geocodingResults.push(result)` vai ser corrida depois do teu `.map`. É a mesma situação que [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137167/129).

Para o map ter o valor que queres tens de correr o resto do código dentro da callback do `geocoder.geocode`.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
function getShortNames(markers) {
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  // tens de criar uma promise para cada chamada assíncrona
  const promises = markers.map(latLong => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'location': latLong
      }, (result, status) => {
        // console.log(results, status)
        if (status !== 'OK') reject();
        else resolve(result);
      })
    });

    // Aqui tens de esperar que todas as callbacks sejam chamadas e depois podes dar um return
    return Promise.all(promises) then((geocodingResults) => {
      return geocodingResults.map((address) => {
        console.log('address', address)
        return address[0].address_components[1].short_name
      })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
}

getShortNames([/*markers*/]).then(names => console.log(names);
```

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129)